# How to connect a web page with android studio to share data?

Tags: php, html, sql, json, android-studio

I have a text box(text view) in android studio and I need to fill it automatically using data(string) passed to a text box in a web page. How do I connect these two? Do I need to use a database? I'm new to android development and any help or idea would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can realize REST service on php backend and receive data via ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly get value from webview page , You can try a hack which is as follows :

Suppose you have TextBox named username in webview now to set username in your webview use get method which shows string data in URL .. 
Now You need to attach a WebViewClient to the WebView to listen in on the URLs that are being fetched. from this you can get data using StringTokenizer to get and set them to android textview.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer("http://www.example.com/auth/loginuser=stackoverfllow", "=");

    while(st1.hasMoreTokens()) {

        System.out.println(st1.nextToken());
username = st1.nextToken();
AndroidTextView.setText(username);

    }
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    //page has finished loading
}
});
```

Comment: I am happy that it was helpful to you . Happy coding :)